# Add Pop-up for database update

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm a new iphone developer and getting ready to launch my first app. I have an reference utility app that I developed with help from an experienced developer to provide a process to upload database update to SQLite from access.  When the updates occur, I have a popup window appearing which prompts the user to accept the data update or not. However, if they accept the update I want a popup to display during the update process. What do I need to do to ad this to this code?

```
   if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"is_update_availableResult"] )
   {
           if([soapResults isEqualToString:@"yes"])
           {
                   soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                   NSString *strMessage=@"An update is available. Select OK to update or cancel to load later. Please wait while system loads data before using app. ";
                   altView=[[UIAlertView alloc] init];
                   altView.title=@"MY APP";
                   altView.delegate=self;
                   [altView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
                   [altView addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
                   [altView setCancelButtonIndex:0];
                   altView.message=strMessage;
                   [altView show];

           }
```

Comment: For what purpose you want the pop up during your database updation and what content you like to show (like "Updating data base").

Comment: While the updation is occurring, I just want a popup to display a progress bar, hourglass or anything similar that will better inform the user that an update is occurring, and prevent from leaving the screen and impacting the upload.  The small pinwheel is too small and I'm concerned users will not see this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to implement the progress indication for your data base operation.
**Declare UIAlertView* myAlert in your class header file.**

```
myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Updating database…" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [myAlert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(myAlert.bounds.size.width / 2, myAlert.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [myAlert addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];
```

Once your database operation is completed dismiss the UIAlertView

```
-(void) OperationCompleted
{
    [myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. However I'm really a novice when it comes to adding this to the file.

Is this in addition to the code that I listed above or instead of?

Can you tell me where to add the { and } of the string?

And do I begin the action with a

-(UITableView *)

myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Updating database.......